# Regex removing all spaces

Tags: python, regex

I am making a bot where if someone does `!redeem <key>` it redeems their key.
However, if people put 2 spaces for example between `!redeem` and their `key` the bot does not work. Is it possible for regex to catch all spaces between `!redeem` and the `key`.

This is my current code

```
redeemkey = message.content.lower()
if redeemkey.startswith('!redeem'):
    redeemkey = re.sub("!redeem ", "", redeemkey)
```

Comment: You are overthinking it, if you ask me. You're trying to replace the prefix and expect the remainder to be the key. Either do a simple split on space and take the last element or do a capture of the last sequence of non-spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by replacing the code snippet as follows:

```
redeemkey = message.content.lower()
if redeemkey.startswith('!redeem'):
    redeemkey = re.sub("!redeem[ ]*", "", redeemkey)
```